# Nuxt - Vuetify Global Configuration for Component Icons

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm looking for set globally the icons for components, for example, I have this for every data tables in my application:

For information: I'm on Nuxt 2 so Vuetify 2

```
<v-data-table
  :header-props="{
    sortIcon: 'fa-arrow-up'
  }"
  :footer-props="{
    showFirstLastPage: true,
    firstIcon: 'fa-angles-left',
    lastIcon: 'fa-angles-right',
    prevIcon: 'fa-angle-left',
    nextIcon: 'fa-angle-right'
  }"
</v-data-table>
```

I tried to set it in nuxt.config.js like that

```
vuetify: {
  defaultAssets: false,
  defaults: {
    VDataTable: {
      headerProps: {
        sortIcon: 'fa-arrow-up'
      },
      footerProps: {
        showFirstLastPage: true,
        firstIcon: 'fa-angles-left',
        lastIcon: 'fa-angles-right',
        prevIcon: 'fa-angle-left',
        nextIcon: 'fa-angle-right'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So how can I set these icons globally ?

Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you configured vuetify inside nuxt. Here is one way to define vuetify global properties using [nuxt-vuetify module](https://nuxt.com/modules/nuxt-vuetify)

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    devtools: {enabled: true},
    modules: [
        '@invictus.codes/nuxt-vuetify'
    ],
    vuetify: {
        moduleOptions: {
            treeshaking: true,
            styles: 'sass',
            autoImport: true,
        },
        vuetifyOptions: {
            defaults: {
                VCard: {
                    elevation: 12,
                },
            },
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I see that this config is for Vuetify 3, I'm on Vuetify 2. I add this information on ticket

Comment: I'm afraid, the feature of setting global config for Vuetify components may not be available for v2. https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9677

Comment: I see, I close the ticket, thanks you Kiran :)